# React-redux dispatch function with parameters from child component is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, formik

I have an action

```
export const saveNewTask = (taskName, taskDescription) => async dispatch => {
  console.log(taskName, taskDescription);
  const res = await axios.post('/api/add-new-task', {
    taskName,
    taskDescription
  });
  console.log(res);
  dispatch({ type: SAVE_TASK, payload: res.data });
};
```

a parent container that contains a child container which is a Formik form and should allow the child component to save the Formik form contents to the db via the above mentioned action.

```
import { saveNewTask } from '../actions/index';

class ClientDashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <NewTask saveNewTask={saveNewTask()} />;
  }
}

export default connect(null, { saveNewTask })(Container);
```

NewTask.js child component that does not know anything about Redux:

```
function NewTask(props) {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      taskName: '',
      taskDescription: ''
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      // alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      props.saveNewTask(values.taskName, values.taskDescription);
    }
  });
...
}
```

but the action never gets the parameters that I am trying to pass through the Formik component (the commented alert line displays both values perfectly) and says both `taskName` and `taskDescription` are undefined. Also the dispatch in the last line of the action says

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function at Object.saveNewTask`

I think this is more of a syntax error than anything else but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
return <NewTask saveNewTask={saveNewTask()} />;
```

1. You need to pass a **prop for calling the action**, *not* the result of the function call.
2. You need to call your prop, not your action creator method.

So, change that line to:

```
return <NewTask saveNewTask={this.props.saveNewTask} />;
```

Comment: Initially this is what I did, but then nothing happens at all, the action is not even called to begin with

Comment: This works! Thanks, but in the official react-redux todo example they call the action creator directly without this.props. Why do we need this.props?

Comment: I don't believe you read it correctly. Can you point me to the resource?

Comment: "https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo" taken from "https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial" under /src/components/Todo.js they use toggleTodo action directly without this.props

Comment: in that example, it clearly states `this.props.addTodo(this.state.input);`.

Comment: or, if you meant `toggleTodo`, you'll see that it's destructured from the functional component's parameter -- which means `props`.

Comment: Ohh, I missed the destructuring part at the top of the functional component's parameters. This clears out everything. Thanks so much again :)